# A question on weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=1+\sin(n\pi x)$. I have to prove that $f_n^k$ converges weakly in $L^1([0,1])$ to
\begin{equation}
c_k:=\underset{a+2b=k}{\sum_{a,b\geq0}}\frac{k!}{a!b!b!}4^{-b}
\end{equation}
for $n\rightarrow+\infty$.

I cannot use Riemann Lebesgue lemma, so I don't know how to do this. Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Since Riemann–Lebesgue lemma is would give an easy proof, it might be helpful to explain why you can't use Riemann–Lebesgue lemma and what kind of results are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Write

\begin{align*}
f_n^k
&= \left( 1 + \frac{i}{2i}e^{n\pi ix} - \frac{1}{2i}e^{-n\pi ix}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{\substack{a,b,c\geq 0 \\a+b+c=k}} \binom{k}{a,b,c} \left(\frac{1}{2i}e^{n\pi ix}\right)^b\left( -\frac{1}{2i}e^{-n\pi ix}\right)^c \\
&= \sum_{\substack{a,b,c\geq 0 \\a+b+c=k}} \binom{k}{a,b,c} \frac{1}{2^{b+c}i^{b-c}} e^{n\pi(b-c)ix}
\end{align*}